# Application.Volatile: Why Doesn't It Work as Expected?

Tags: vba, excel

I created a function and saved it in the main module, as follows:

```
Public Function Teste() As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    MsgBox "rodou"
    Teste = ""
End Function
```

**Calculation Options** is set to *Automatic*. In the cell, I placed the formula (eg. *=Teste()*), expecting that **Teste** function would run, everytime I would modify any cell because **Application.Volatile** sets my function as *Dirty*, forcing Excel to run the function.

What happens is that **Teste** function is not called, unless I put any of the cells that will be updated in the **Change** event of the worksheet (eg. *=Teste(B2)*).

What I want is just to run **Teste** function everytime I do changes in the worksheet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent That is not right. Excel does recalculate volatile functions on any change of any cell in any workbook. This behaviour is the very point of `Volatile`. In fact I cannot reproduce the OP's problem, I get the message box whenever I change any cell.

Comment: Documentation says: "_This method has no effect if it's not inside a user-defined function __used to calculate a worksheet cell___". Qeustion is whether that means the function is used in a worksheet cell or the function modifies (another) worksheet cell in its code.Excel can know whether the function does or does not when it compiles. This function does not modify a worksheet cell in its code, hence might not be called.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The documentation means "This method has no effect unless the function was placed in a cell." If you create a function and only use it in code, never placing it in any cell, `Volatile` will have no effect. Also, [no VBA function is allowed to change any cells](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13705663/11683).

Comment: @CSerg, huh? "Also, no VBA function is allowed to change any cells". `AcriveSheet.Cells("A1")= 123`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes, that will not work if executed from a function called from a cell.

Comment: @CSerg, didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915312/how-vba-declared-volatility-works?rq=1

Comment: stop the fight, please! I need help. hahahaha... just kidding. If I understood, my code is right but Excel is not working properly. So, what now?

Comment: Maybe you have disabled automatic recalculation?

Comment: hi @Vegard. as I said before, calculation is set to automatic.

Answer (score 0):

it's working now! after compiling VBA code, **Teste** function is now running everytime I do changes in any cell of the worksheet. this information is in the post shared by @Paul Ogilvie ([stackoverflow.com/questions/29915312/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915312/how-vba-declared-volatility-works?rq=1)).

thank you all for the prompt help!